# Why aren't my landscape resources getting generated by ionic cordova referesh?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to generate a set of splash screens and icons for my app.

When I run `iconic cordova references` it generates 40 images based on my base splash and icon png's. However there are 60 images that need to be updated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an orientation setup for your application in the `config.xml` file, only the files for the relevant orientations are generated.

In this specific example, removing the following "portrait" orientation temporarily:

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
```

allows for the landscape images to be generated. That gets 56/60 - the remainder being iPad specific images, where I presume there's a similar solution.

That said, the landscape images "should" be irrelevant in a portrait only application.